# Compare JSON objects replied by getJSON and output new object after removing elements

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have two api calls that replies with JSON objects using getJSON:

```
$.getJSON(url1).then(function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
            console.log(item);
        });
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

the scound one will is the same but with diferent url
say the first fuction will reply json data:

```
[
{"_id":"1","caller_id":"234567","user_id":"5"},
{"_id":"2","caller_id":"345678","user_id":"3"},
{"_id":"3","caller_id":"456789","user_id":"4"},
{"_id":"4","caller_id":"123456","user_id":"1"}
]
```

the second will reply with:

```
[
{"telefono":"234567"},
{"telefono":"111111"},
{"telefono":"456789"},
{"telefono":"222222"},
{"telefono":"345678"},
{"telefono":"333333"},
{"telefono":"123456"},
]
```

how can I Compare the two JSON objects and output result into new object after removing elements where:

> json1.caller_id = json2.telefono

The inspected result:

```
[
{"telefono":"111111"},
{"telefono":"222222"},
{"telefono":"333333"},
]
```

**EDIT:**

based on @gaetanoM answer: This code works for me:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON("/api_1"),
    $.getJSON("/api_2")
).done(function(data1, data2) {
    console.log(data1[0]);
    console.log(data2[0]);
    var x = data1[0].reduce((a, e) => {a[ e.caller_id] = true; return a}, {});
   datos = data2[0].filter((e) => x[e.telefono] == undefined);
   //    .... what ever
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the first array of objects as a key/value pair where:

- key is **caller_id value**
- value is true or another value

After this, you can filter the second array looking for into the first:

```js
var firstobj = [
    {"_id":"1","caller_id":"234567","user_id":"5"},
    {"_id":"2","caller_id":"345678","user_id":"3"},
    {"_id":"3","caller_id":"456789","user_id":"4"},
    {"_id":"4","caller_id":"123456","user_id":"1"}
];
var secondobj = [
    {"telefono":"234567"},
    {"telefono":"111111"},
    {"telefono":"456789"},
    {"telefono":"222222"},
    {"telefono":"345678"},
    {"telefono":"333333"},
    {"telefono":"123456"},
];
var x = firstobj.reduce((a, e) => {a[ e.caller_id] = true; return a}, {});
secondobj = secondobj.filter((e) => x[e.telefono] == undefined);

console.log(secondobj);
```

Comment: it works fine if json  assigned to variable, but I get data from api calls. I tried:  $.when(
    $.getJSON("/api_1"),
    $.getJSON("/api_2")
).done(function(data1, data2) {
    console.log(data1[0]);
    console.log(data2[0]);
    var x = data1[0].reduce((a, e) => {a[ e.caller_id] = true; return a}, {});
dato = data2[0].filter((e) => x[e.telefono] == undefined);
console.log( dato);
}); and get : [object Object],[object Object] ...

Comment: you get  [object Object],[object Object] ...  because your apis don't return expected values. Inspect the browser (i.e.: F12) and see what the data1 or data2  contain.